# Can you use the delta method for number fields?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I have seen a few papers using the delta symbol method (after Heath-Brown's [*A New Form of the Circle Method*](https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1996.481.149) and [Duke-Friedlander-Iwaniec's paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01231758)), where one creatively expands the delta symbol. Are there some examples, where this has been used successfully in the context of number fields?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. See the paper:

- Browning, T. D.; Vishe, P. *Cubic hypersurfaces and a version of the circle method for number fields*, Duke Math. J. **163** (2014), no. 10, 1825–1883, doi:[10.1215/00127094-2738530](https://doi.org/10.1215/00127094-2738530), [arXiv:1207.2385](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2385).